# Multiple recordset paging PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, paging, recordset

I have two separate recordsets on a page used.

the first one 'images' shows only one entry at a time.

the second one 'images2' shows 6 entries at a time.

Both of these recordsets have recordset paging, so I can move to the next/previous 'page' (ie if I page 'images' I get another single entry, if I page 'images2' I get the next six etc).

My problem is that by paging either 'images' or 'images2' resets the other to it's first record..... so if I'm on page 4 of 'images' and then want to page to page 2 'images2', clicking the link causes 'images' to return to page 1 while I do move to page 2 of 'images2'... confused yet?

I'm guessing what I need to do is combine the recordset paging links together and put them on both links, so that clicking either of the paging links works, but not entirely sure the best way to proceed. Anyone any guidance?

I'm attaching code for one of the links 'images2' and the code for both recordsets

many thanks in advance

Code for link

```
<?php if ($pageNum_images2 < $totalPages_images2) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_images2=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_images2, $pageNum_images2 + 1), $queryString_images2); ?>"><img src="images/image-controls/right-arrow.png" width="15" height="42" alt=""/></a>

  <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
```

Code for 'images'

```
$maxRows_images = 1;
$pageNum_images = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_images'])) {
  $pageNum_images = $_GET['pageNum_images'];
}
$startRow_images = $pageNum_images * $maxRows_images;

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_images = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE gallery = 'art' AND status = 'a' ORDER BY `key` ASC";
$query_limit_images = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_images, $startRow_images, $maxRows_images);
$images = mysql_query($query_limit_images, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($images);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_images'])) {
  $totalRows_images = $_GET['totalRows_images'];
} else {
  $all_images = mysql_query($query_images);
  $totalRows_images = mysql_num_rows($all_images);
}
$totalPages_images = ceil($totalRows_images/$maxRows_images)-1;
```

code for 'images2'

```
$maxRows_images2 = 6;
$pageNum_images2 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_images2'])) {
  $pageNum_images2 = $_GET['pageNum_images2'];
}
$startRow_images2 = $pageNum_images2 * $maxRows_images2;

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_images2 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE gallery = 'art' AND status = 'a' ORDER BY `key` ASC";
$query_limit_images2 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_images2, $startRow_images2, $maxRows_images2);
$images2 = mysql_query($query_limit_images2, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_images2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($images2);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_images2'])) {
  $totalRows_images2 = $_GET['totalRows_images2'];
} else {
  $all_images2 = mysql_query($query_images2);
  $totalRows_images2 = mysql_num_rows($all_images2);
}
$totalPages_images2 = ceil($totalRows_images2/$maxRows_images2)-1;
```

Comment: Include both 'pageNum_' in every url that is on the page so you can work out where you are in both recordsets?

Comment: thanks - I think I'd just worked it out and you said that - many thanks for your comment Ryan